# Can not call OpenWhisk web action from browser

Tags: openwhisk

How can I call a web action from my browser, when my OpenWhisk deployment is on a company sandbox server?

I have an OpenWhisk deployment setup on a company sandbox server using this guide: [Deploying OpenWhisk on kind](https://github.com/apache/openwhisk-deploy-kube/blob/master/docs/k8s-kind.md). The server is running CentOS 7. I created a web action and I am able to call with `curl -k https://apiHostName:apiHostPort/api/v1/web/guest/demo/hello?name=myName` where apiHostName and apiHostPort are the values defined in mycluster.yaml. However, trying to access the above url from my browser returns ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.

```
[root[DEV]@vx3a27 wskcluster]# kubectl -n openwhisk get svc
NAME               TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)                      AGE
owdev-apigateway   ClusterIP   10.96.9.60      A.B.C.D        8080/TCP,9000/TCP            6d1h
owdev-controller   ClusterIP   10.96.104.180   <none>         8080/TCP                     6d1h
owdev-couchdb      ClusterIP   10.96.40.104    <none>         5984/TCP                     6d1h
owdev-kafka        ClusterIP   None            <none>         9092/TCP                     6d1h
owdev-nginx        NodePort    10.96.84.3      A.B.C.D        80:31486/TCP,443:31001/TCP   6d1h
owdev-redis        ClusterIP   10.96.84.177    <none>         6379/TCP                     6d1h
owdev-zookeeper    ClusterIP   None            <none>         2181/TCP,2888/TCP,3888/TCP   6d1h
```

I have tried setting the external API of both my nginx and apigateway services as seen above, where A.B.C.D is the IP of my sandbox obtained with `ifconfig`. Running both `curl -k` and the browser with A.B.C.D yields ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

What else can I try to get this to work?